# How to prove Legendre Polynomials' recurrence relation without using explicit formula?

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Assume there is an inner product on linear space $V = \{ \text{polynormials}\}$:
$$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 w(t) f(t)g(t) dt$$ with $w(t) \ge 0$ and not identically zero.

Then we can construct general [Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) with coefficient of highest degree = 1
$$p_0(x) = 1$$
$$p_i(x) = x^i - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\frac{\langle x^i, p_j\rangle}{\langle p_j, p_j\rangle} p_j$$

These are orthogonal basis for $V$.

Only by these conditions, how to prove there exist $a_i$ and $b_i$ such that
$$x p_{i-1}(x) = p_i(x) + a_i p_{i-1}(x) + b_i p_{i-2}(x)$$
similiar to [recurrence relation of Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Recurrence_relations).

I know for Legendre Polynomials, we use generating function to prove these relations. How to prove these for generic weight?

My attempt:
$$p_i(x) = x^i - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}c^i_j p_j$$
with $c^i_j = \frac{\langle x^i, p_j\rangle}{\langle p_j, p_j\rangle}$

$$x p_{i-1}(x) = x^i - \sum_{j=0}^{i-2}c^{i-1}_j x p_j$$

$$ x p_{i-1} - p_i = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}c^i_j p_j - \sum_{j=0}^{i-2}c^{i-1}_j (p_{j+1} + a_{j+1}p_j + b_{j+1} p_{j-1})$$

From coefficients of $p_{i-1}$ and $p_{i-2}$, we can get $a_i$ and $b_i$ formula. However, I cannot show coefficients of $p_j$ with $j < i - 2$ will cancel each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The following is an adapted translation of [Wikipedia.fr, Suite_de_polynômes_orthogonaux#Relation_de_récurrence](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_de_polyn%C3%B4mes_orthogonaux#Relation_de_r%C3%A9currence).*

Let us prove that
$$p_{n+1}=(x+b_n)p_n-c_np_{n-1}$$
where
$$b_n=k_{n+1}-
k_n,\qquad c_n=\frac{h_n}{h_{n-1}},$$
$k_j,h_j$ being given by
$$p_j(x)=x^j+k_jx^{j-1}+\cdots,\quad h_j=\langle p_j,p_j \rangle.$$

(By convention, $c_0=p_{-1}=k_0=0.$)

The polynomial
$(x+b_n)p_n–p_{n+1}$ has a degree $<n$ hence may be written $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mu_{n,j}p_j,$
with
$h_j\mu_{n,j}=\langle (x+b_n)p_n-p_{n+1},p_j\rangle=\langle xp_n,p_j\rangle$
(since for $j<n,$ $p_j$ is orthogonal to $p_n$ and to $p_{n+1}$).

Moreover,
$\langle xp_n,p_j\rangle=\langle p_n,xp_j\rangle.$

- For $j<n-1,$ this inner product is $0$ because $\deg(x p_j)<n.$
- For $j=n-1,$ it is equal to $h_n$ because (reasoning like previously) $x p_{n-1}–p_n$ has a degree $<n.$

We may conclude:
$(x+b_n)p_n-p_{n+1}= c_np_{n-1},$
where $c_n=\mu_{n,n-1}=\frac{h_n}{h_{n-1}}.$